# Can one give an example of the converse statement of Fubini's theorem fails to exist?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Can one find an $f$ on $\mathbb{R}²$ which is integral-undefined on $\mathbb{R}²$ , but $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y) {\rm d}x{\rm d}y=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y){\rm d}y{\rm d}x<∞$$

**The integrals mentioned in here are all referring to the Lebesgue Integrals, and the integral-undeined  means $\int f^+,\int f^-$ are both infinity.**

I asked this question  because I am learning the Fubini-Toneli's theorem, which states as:

> if $f(x,y)$ is integral-defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$ , then for a.e $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d_1},y\in\mathbb{R}^{d_2}$,there holds  $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}}f(x,y) {\rm d}x{\rm d}y=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}f(x,y){\rm d}y{\rm d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x,y){\rm d}(x,y)$$

And I just wanna to know whether the converse statement is true.

Comment: How do you want to take integral of something that isn't defined in the first place!

Comment: @Jakobian Sorry, I don't get "isn't defined" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much  ， I will find !

Comment: It is on page 166.

Comment: yeah~also，the Fikhedingorts' course of calculus ,vol 3 also has a counter example, thank you very much.